# Progress Dialog - WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog, android-windowmanager

I am having one **MapActivity** in which first of all I am trying to fetch the current location of the user. For getting the current location I used the **AsyncTask** concept. Now What I am trying to achieve is to show the **ProgressDialog** to the user until got the current location.

**Here is the Layout code :-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:apiKey="0nO35c3MpXJisxsknk_w_fqVQa78sPhMQK3Yf5w"
        android:clickable="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/zoombar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:max="20"
            android:progress="0" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:background="@drawable/round"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="5dip" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/sun" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dip" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/rupee"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/rupee" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/day_amount"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                    android:numeric="decimal"
                    android:text="0.0"
                    android:textColor="@color/autoText"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="2dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#ff6600" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="5dip" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/moon" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dip" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/rupee"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/rupee" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/night_amount"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                    android:numeric="decimal"
                    android:text="0.0"
                    android:textColor="@color/autoText"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**MapActivity Code :-**

```
// Background AsyncTask Class

    class CurrentPositionTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
        boolean flag = true;
        @Override
        public void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("Executed");

                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    dialog = new ProgressDialog(AutoMapActivity.this.getApplicationContext());
                    dialog.setTitle("");
                    dialog.setMessage("Searching");
                    dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        public Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            while(flag){
                //System.out.println("While Loop");
                if (latitude != 0 && longitude != 0) {
                    flag = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
            if (latitude!=0 && longitude!=0) {
                dialog.cancel();
                setInit();
            }
        }
    }

    //LocationListner Class
    class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (location != null) {
                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                longitude = location.getLongitude();
            }
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gps Disabled",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gps Enabled",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extra) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch (status) {
            case 0:
                // OutofService
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Out of Service",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            case 1:
                // Temporarily unavailable
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Location Temporary Unavailable", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
                break;
            case 2:
                // Available
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Available",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

**LOG CAT :-**'

```
07-17 19:37:49.267: W/System.err(881): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
07-17 19:37:49.277: W/System.err(881):  at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:531)
07-17 19:37:49.277: W/System.err(881):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:177)
07-17 19:37:49.277: W/System.err(881):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
07-17 19:37:49.277: W/System.err(881):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
07-17 19:37:49.277: W/System.err(881):  at com.test.fare.AutoMapActivity$CurrentPositionTask.onPreExecute(AutoMapActivity.java:195)
07-17 19:37:49.277: W/System.err(881):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:391)
07-17 19:37:49.277: W/System.err(881):  at com.test.fare.AutoMapActivity.getUserCurrentLocation(AutoMapActivity.java:146)
07-17 19:37:49.277: W/System.err(881):  at com.test.fare.AutoMapActivity.onCreate(AutoMapActivity.java:80)
07-17 19:37:49.277: W/System.err(881):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-17 19:37:49.287: W/System.err(881):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
07-17 19:37:49.287: W/System.err(881):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
07-17 19:37:49.287: W/System.err(881):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
07-17 19:37:49.287: W/System.err(881):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
07-17 19:37:49.287: W/System.err(881):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-17 19:37:49.287: W/System.err(881):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
07-17 19:37:49.287: W/System.err(881):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
07-17 19:37:49.297: W/System.err(881):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-17 19:37:49.297: W/System.err(881):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-17 19:37:49.297: W/System.err(881):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
07-17 19:37:49.297: W/System.err(881):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
07-17 19:37:49.297: W/System.err(881):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In MapActivity try using AutoMapActivity.this instead of AutoMapActivity.this.getApplicationContext() when creating the dialog?

Comment: Great. Its working fine now. Can you please tell me why its giving error when using getApplicationContext()??

Comment: The dialog is tied to this particular activity, and not the entire application. Generally use Activity.this when creating objects whose scope is just the activity. Use Application context when you are creating objects whose scope is beyond the current activity.

Comment: Hmmm. Thanks for information. I knew this concept but didn't think on this. Once again thanks...